# How to open a Visual Studio Code workspace in a new window

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, can I open a workspace in a new window in one keystroke? I tried using the [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros) extension, defining the following:

```
"macros": {
    "openWorkspaceNewWindow": [
        "workbench.action.newWindow",
        "workbench.action.openWorkspace"
    ]
}
```

which does, in fact, open a new window, but then it ignores the new as it calls `openWorkspace`.

What I'm trying to do is not replace the current window with the newly opened workspace; I want to retain the current window and open a new one with the workspace in it.

Comment: I'm unable to open a new window and then open the workspace in that window in the GUI. When I do, nothing happens, and the files don't show up in the VSC explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extension does what I want:

https://github.com/sadesyllas/vscode-workspace-switcher

Answer (score 20):

On Windows/Linux - File > Preferences > Settings
On macOS - Code > Preferences > Settings

search: open folders in new window
set: ON

Comment: I turned it on, now how can i use it?

Answer (score 6):

You can change the editor behaviour by holding the (**macOS**: `Option` key or `Cmd` key, **win**: `Ctrl` key or `Shift` key) when opening from `File > Open Recent > ...`

You can also set the settings as well to do it as a default:

```json
"window.openFoldersInNewWindow": "on"
```

Answer (score 0):

CTRL + P : workspaces : "Duplicate as a workspace in a new folder" alternatively you can put a shortcut for it with "CTRL+K+S" to open keybinds settings and search for it and replace CTRL + SHIFT + N which opens a blank workspace. Furthermore few remarks that can help in developement :

- you can use "Switch window" (by default it doesn't have a shortcut) to switch between window in the same workspace.
- you can use CTRL + R to change between projects and hold CTRL in that menu so you can open it in a new window.

Hope that helps my fellow Programmers :).